# Can friends see scheduled gifts in my inventory?

Tags: steam

I will be without internet for a couple months so I scheduled a game to be gifted while I'm gone.  Is he able to look through my inventory and see the game I am giving him?

Answer (score 1):

No he can not. Items that you are gifting should not be able to be seen by the person you are gifting it to. This is from my experience and none of my friends have been able to see from my inventory.